# Why aren't all my settings in the user.config file?

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

I'm writing an application which can edit some of of the user settings, which I define in the Settings.settings. once I run the application I can see find the application's data store in:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\\\ but the file only seems to have the options that I write programatically not the ones that I set as defaults.

All the settings are user settings not Application settings, and they seem to be being picked up from somewhere.

Where else could they be?

I've noticed that there are two product folders with hashes post-pended to their names, one is of the format .exe_Url_ the other is .vshost.exe_Url_ neither of these have the missing data in them though.

Answer (score 0):

The settings that are still at their defaults and the global settings are in the application's config file which is in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: That file is empty aside from the following: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>

Comment: That is in the debug folder though.

Comment: How did you configure the settings? Can you post the code and or screenshots?

Comment: The settings are configured in Visual Studio if you double click on the Settings.settings file it gives you a table. I'm saving them using MyNameSpace.Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); having changed them. The ones that I change appear in the file the ones that I don't are missing.

Comment: I just tried it with a console application. In the Debug folder is a ConsoleApplication.exe.config which contains the default value: `<value>42</value>` under user settings. If it is not there, could you share a minimal example?